# Malformed SQL92 string at position: 5. Expecting "call"?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

As of the title I am getting an exception while trying to call an Oracle function from my Java code.
I tried few things but didn't worked. At this point I am not sure what to do. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

`Java`

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("{? = CALL FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
         cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

         cstmt.setString(2, "SCR");
         cstmt.setString(3,l_srccur);
         cstmt.setString(4, l_tfcurr);
         cstmt.setString(5, "B001");

         cstmt.execute();
         res = cstmt.getString(1);
```

`Oracle Function`

```
FUNCTION FXRATE_ENTITY(CODCURRBASE IN VARCHAR, LCODCURRFROM IN VARCHAR, LCODCURRTO IN VARCHAR, LIDENTITY IN VARCHAR)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  CODCUR_L VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  IF (LCODCURRTO = '*') THEN
    RETURN NVL(FXRATE(CODCURRBASE, LCODCURRFROM, CODCURRBASE, LIDENTITY),
               0);
  ELSE
    RETURN NVL(FXRATE(CODCURRBASE, LCODCURRFROM, LCODCURRTO, LIDENTITY), 0);
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

A) You're using SQL92 syntax (with the curly brackets {}). I think for this option, "call" needs to be in lower case.

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("{? = call FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?)}")
```

B) The Oracle SQL statement `CALL` [can be used for functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4008.htm#SQLRF01108), but you need the `INTO` clause. Since your OUT parameter now goes at the end, reorder your parameter statements.

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("CALL FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?) INTO ?");
cstmt.setString(1, "SCR");
cstmt.setString(2,l_srccur);
cstmt.setString(3, l_tfcurr);
cstmt.setString(4, "B001");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

B) Instead of CALL, you can use a PL/SQL anonymous block, [like this example](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html):

```
CallableStatement cstmt = p_con.prepareCall("begin ? := FXRATE_ENTITY(?, ?, ?, ?); end;");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setString(2, "SCR");
cstmt.setString(3,l_srccur);
cstmt.setString(4, l_tfcurr);
cstmt.setString(5, "B001");
```

Comment: Neither explains the error. Do you know why the error is throwing ?

Comment: Hmm you're right, Oracle does support that jdbc call syntax... try making "CALL" in lower case, "call". https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-BE5C683E-0A2F-42D1-AF9B-7854BFAC4D53

Comment: For the first one i got an exception ```java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 41:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( % ;
The symbol ":= was inserted before "INTO" to continue. ```

Comment: for the second one i got ```java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement```

Comment: You probably cannot set a variable's name to place the result in that variable. But maybe you want a similar procedure with an extra output parameter receiving a string `'SCR'`.

Comment: @kfinity Thank you. It took me while to find your answer and understand that the "call" keyword must be lower case for a function call using SQL92 syntax.